# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'PureJavaClasses.employeeClass' does not have the property 'Id'

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, el

I have been trying to print a ResultSet inside a JSP with the help of a Servlet through an ArrayList.The JDBC part seems all right.The ArrayList can be obtained inside the JSP and can be printed.But when I want to iterate the list passed onto the JSP with the `<c:forEach>` tag,the it is saying that my bean class 'PureJavaClasses.employeeClass' doesn't have the attribute 'Id'. I have tried a bunch of different solutions posted on SO but all in vain.I am out of ideas about what to do.I am a total beginner in JavaEE.

Here is my Bean class:

```
public class employeeClass implements java.io.Serializable {
private int id;
private String name;
private String job;
private int subjectId;
private int salary;

public employeeClass() {

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getJob() {
    return job;
}

public void setJob(String job) {
    this.job = job;
}

public int getSubjectid() {
    return subjectId;
}

public void setSubjectid(int subjectId) {
    this.subjectId = subjectId;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return  "id=" + id +
            ", name=" + name +
            ", job=" + job +
            ", subjectId=" + subjectId +
            ", salary=" + salary;
}
}
```

Here is the servlet:

```
private void show_table(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
    Connection connection = ServletLogin.connection;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM `dog`.`employee`";
    ArrayList<employeeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            employeeClass obj2 = new employeeClass();
            obj2.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
            obj2.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
            obj2.setJob(rs.getString("Job_Designation"));
            obj2.setSubjectid(rs.getInt("Subject ID"));
            obj2.setSalary(rs.getInt("Salary"));
            list.add(obj2);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    request.setAttribute("listEmp",list);
    try {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Pages/EmployeeTable.jsp").forward(request,response);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my EmployeeTable.jsp :

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Employee List</title>
</head>
<body>
<% ArrayList list1 =(ArrayList) request.getAttribute("listEmp"); %>
<%=list1%>
    <table>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Job Designation</th>
        <th>Subject ID</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <c:forEach items="${listEmp}" var="list">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${list.Id}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${list.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${list.job}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${list.subjectId}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${list.salary}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletLogin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ServletLogin</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletEmployee</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ServletEmployee</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletLogin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletLogin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletEmployee</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletEmployee</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: <td><c:out value="${list.Id}"/></td> ... list.Id should be list.id

Comment: the i in id should not be capital

Comment: Still no result as of no(1edit).Same old "PropertyNotFoundExcecption"

Comment: if you comment out that line, does it output other lines such as name and job?

Comment: @FarazDurrani Now it's subjectId.But when I comment out subjectId then it works fine.

Comment: ok no problem. in your show_table method, try to print out rs.getInt("ID"), see if you can get any value out of it

Comment: also try to pint out subjectid

Comment: @FarazDurrani problem solved.Naming conventions are very strict.I made very fine mistakes in them.I changed from "subjectID" to "subjectid" and then everything was fine.Thanks for the help.Learn't an important lesson tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to fix by providing correct names. Like use id instead of Id, etc. That should solve it.

```
<td><c:out value="${list.id}"/></td>
```